# Find nodes with more than one common relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I used `CREATE UNIQUE` to identify nodes with one common relationship:

```
MATCH (u1:User)-[a:Score]->(g:Games)<-[b:Score]-(u2:User)
WITH u1, u2
CREATE UNIQUE (u1)-[:Common]->(u2)
```

but I have problem when I want to identify nodes when users have more than one (e.g. 3) common relationships with showing the number of games the pair of users has in common. I have tried different queries and this is one of them:

```
MATCH (u1:User)-[a:Score]->(g:Games)<-[b:Score]-(u2:User)
MATCH (u1)-[a:Score]->(g1:Games), (u1)-[b:Score]->(g2:games)
WITH u1, u2, COUNT(DISTINCT s1) AS s1Count, COUNT(DISTINCT s2) AS s2Count
MATCH (u1)-[a:Score]->(g:Games)<-[b:Score]-(u2)
WITH u1, u2, s1Count, s2Count, COUNT(g) AS commonGamesCount
WHERE commonGamesCount >= 3
RETURN u1, u2
```

I want to see the results exactly like `CREATE UNIQUE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count common relationships:

```
MATCH (u1:User)-[a:Score]->(g:Games)<-[b:Score]-(u2:User)
WITH u1, u2, count(g) as g_count
WHERE g_count >= 3
CREATE UNIQUE (u1)-[:Common3]->(u2)
```